# What is the name of this line-connecting game?

Tags: puzzle-identification, game

Can you tell me what is the name of the game I used to play in school?

It's a game for two players. You need grid paper and two pens.

The game is played on a 10x10 arena, shifted by half a grid to one side.

The players take turns, each drawing a one grid length line. One player plays "middles", the other plays "edges", that means one of the players draws lines over the lines of the grid, the other connects centers of adjacent boxes the grid forms. Lines of the two players can't cross - if there's a line drawn on the grid line between two adjacent boxes, the player playing middles can't connect them, and vice versa.

The winner is the one to connect their "own" sides of the grid - "middle" - left and right, "edge" - top and bottom. Below is an example image of the game in progress.

[image: Game in progress]

What is the name of this game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called [Bridg-It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridg-It#Gale), or [Game of Gale](http://www.papg.com/show?1TPI) (as it was invented by David Gale). It is the rectangular grid equivalent of the [Shannon switching game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_switching_game), which is a generalized version of [Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29).

Comment: An old puzzle book I have renames it as "Hugs and Kisses" because it uses `o` and `x` rather than different coloured dots.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I believe using grid paper instead of drawing the dots or `x` and `o` makes the game much more compelling, as preparing the 'board' becomes trivial.

Comment: @SF. only if you already have grid paper to hand. If you have to draw it yourself then there is little difference.