# Intellectual numerical puzzle of different sizes

Tags: puzzle-creation, board-games, puzzle-identification

There is an intellectual puzzle 3x3, as in the photo:

[image]

You need to get an ordered set by moving the buttons through an empty area, like:

[image]

Question: Is a 4x4, 5x5, 6x6 game possible?

Sub-question: Does this game have an official name?

Thanks in advance for any comment/answer!

Comment: Should not this be in beta group, as this is not actually a puzzle.

Comment: @Pandey_Ji Yes, you are probably right.

Comment: Why not add the tag [`puzzle-identification`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification)? This is essential to the original spirit of this site, as far back as [question #80](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80/what-is-the-name-of-this-line-connecting-game).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game is usually referred to as a [Sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle)

The most famous example is the [15 Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) ($4 \times 4$ version)
In this example, half of all the possible starting positions are solvable. In particular, if we switch the 15 and 14, then the puzzle becomes unsolvable. (see Sam Loyd's unsolvable 15-puzzle).

**Higher order examples**
Although I have not seen physical example of $5 \times 5$ or $6 \times 6$, I have seen some online, see here for example: https://www.castleviewuk.com/stp_bk_6x6.html
Googling about might give you some better results.

If you like these types of puzzles you may also enjoy

> [Rush Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_(puzzle))
> [Klotski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klotski)

Comment: On a side note, I think spoiler isn't necessary (?)

Comment: @hexomino Thank You very much for the detailed answer and links!

Comment: @athin, yes, you're right, force of habit! I'll take them out.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Is a 4x4, 5x5, 6x6 game possible?

Yes! This puzzle can be played with arbitrary size such as in [Tatham's version](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/js/fifteen.html). You can play it in your browser or download a Windows executable from [the main page that is full of other puzzles too](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles)!

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Why so? It answers the **main** question "Is a 4x4, 5x5, 6x6 game possible?".

Comment: Agreed, the comment was automatically sent from review. I still think would be better as a comment, as hex has provided a full answer and this doesn’t contribute too much else apart from some useful links, but I agree it does answer the question

Comment: The question has been answered, and the answer has been accepted. This only provides an additional reference. It is better suited as a comment, on either the question or the accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielMathias: So what if an answer has been accepted? Since the beginning the SE guidelines have encouraged multiple helpful answers, and never once said that an accepted answer indicates that nobody else should answer. I posted my answer only because the currently accepted one links to an **inferior** version.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Thanks for responding! See my above comment for why I think my answer should not be just a comment.

Comment: @user21820 Thank You for the answer and links!